# (notice) child pid XXXX exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I keep getting the follow error in my Apache log:

```
[Wed Sep 18 17:59:20 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Sep 18 18:06:30 2013] [notice] child pid 7505 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Wed Sep 18 18:06:35 2013] [notice] child pid 7497 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Wed Sep 18 18:13:53 2013] [notice] child pid 7501 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Wed Sep 18 18:13:53 2013] [notice] child pid 7506 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Wed Sep 18 18:14:14 2013] [notice] child pid 8708 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
```

I've tried to backtrace it by doing the following:

```
user:~$ sudo gdb
user     8670  8571  0 18:12 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto httpd
user:~$ sudo gdb

(gdb) attach 8571
Attaching to process 8571
Reading symbols from /bin/bash...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2...(no debugging symbols      found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2
0x00007f553000244e in waitpid () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007f553000244e in waitpid () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000000000441419 in ?? ()
#2  0x000000000044255c in wait_for ()
#3  0x0000000000432c88 in execute_command_internal ()
#4  0x00000000004352fe in execute_command ()
#5  0x000000000041e31d in reader_loop ()
#6  0x000000000041ca87 in main ()

(gdb) backtrace full
#0  0x00007f553000244e in waitpid () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x0000000000441419 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x000000000044255c in wait_for ()
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x0000000000432c88 in execute_command_internal ()
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00000000004352fe in execute_command ()
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x000000000041e31d in reader_loop ()
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x000000000041ca87 in main ()
No symbol table info available.`
```

I can't make head or tale of the problem.

I've also run gdb on apache as follows:

```
user:~$ sudo gdb apache2
Reading symbols from /usr/sbin/apache2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.

(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/sbin/apache2
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
apache2: bad user name ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
[Inferior 1 (process 6925) exited with code 01]
```

I don't know if it's related to this issue but as soon as I installed gdb the following message is shown when I log in:

```
=> There were exceptions while processing one or more plugins. See
 /var/log/landscape/sysinfo.log for more information.
```

sysinfo.log contains the following:

```
for process_info in info.get_all_process_info():
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/landscape/lib/process.py", line 49, in get_all_process_info
process_info = self.get_process_info(process_id)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/landscape/lib/process.py", line 85, in get_process_info
process_info["state"] = STATES[state]
KeyError: 't (tracing stop)'
2013-09-18 18:43:35,633 ERROR    Processes plugin raised an exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/landscape/sysinfo/sysinfo.py", line 99, in run
result = plugin.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/landscape/sysinfo/processes.py", line 18, in run
for process_info in info.get_all_process_info():
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/landscape/lib/process.py", line 49, in get_all_process_info
process_info = self.get_process_info(process_id)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/landscape/lib/process.py", line 85, in get_process_info
process_info["state"] = STATES[state]
KeyError: 't (tracing stop)'
```

Some background.

I'm running a WordPress site off my VPS. The VPS is an Ubuntu based LAMP server with PERL and CURL installed. I use APC for caching but my segmentation faults occured before I installed APC. Finally I run my server throught Google PageSpeed Service so I have install the mod_remoteip mod for Apache 2.2 and have an X-Forwarded-For header in place.

ulimit core is unlimited.
My phpinfo() file can be found here: http://tecne.ws/11v

Please assist. It would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 11):

I had this issue and changed `LogLevel warn` to `LogLevel debug` in the apache config. On restart it seemed to be segfaulting just after mod_deflate.

Turning off mod_deflate in debian/ubuntu should just be `sudo a2dismod deflate`

Answer (score 3):

I solved this indirectly. I put Nginx in front of Apache and I no longer have segmentation errors. Having Nginx in front of Apache is a better set up in my opinion. Varnish Cache may have also solved the problem.

Comment: I would ditch Apache altogether and just run `nginx` to FPM.

Comment: I prefer Apache to PHP-FPM. I'm more familiar with it.

Comment: We've switched entirely over to nginx/fpm and the performance increases alone are worth it. It's actually pretty easy to configure and run. You should check it out at least. It's never good to get complacent in our industry.

Answer (score 3):

Try to set

`max_input_time = -1`

in your php.ini file.

> from php.ini...
>
> `; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data. It's a good; idea to limit this time on productions servers in order to eliminate unexpectedly
>   ; long running scripts.
>   ; Note: This directive is hardcoded to -1 for the CLI SAPI
>   ; Default Value: -1 (Unlimited)
>   ; Development Value: 60 (60 seconds)
>   ; Production Value: 60 (60 seconds)
>   ; http://php.net/max-input-time`;

Answer (score 3):

This problem is often caused by an Apache module. As you can see, the other answers are about a module or another. The generic answer could be **try to disable the last module(s) you enabled**.

In my case, the module causing the problem is php7.3, on Ubuntu 18.04. PHP 7.2 works, but not PHP 7.3.

Comment: This is a good answer except that this issue is caused more often due to bad PHP modules than a2 modules. I'm using the php package from a tap provided by shivammathur on macOS. I had installed the imap extension from that tap which caused the issue, disabling it worked for me. Like suggested in the solution, you'll have to figure out which module to disable, try doing one by one if you are not sure.

Comment: this answer helped me. in my case i disabled the LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.4/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so and enabled back LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so

Answer (score 2):

I just restarted Apache and the problem gone

Answer (score 1):

After an entire day of trying to trace this down, no solutions worked. I eventually however turned Apache to debug level logging and immediately noticed hundreds of notices/warnings with Google's mod_pagespeed for Apache trying to rewrite images from Jetpack's Photon images.

I did a simple **a2dismod pagespeed** and no more segmentation faults.

Have also noticed my sites are actually running faster now with mod pagespeed turned off.

There seems to be quite a few bug reports about pagespeed causing segmentation faults.

Not sure if its just mod_pagespeed or the combination of mod_pagespeed, wordpress and php .... but turned off now problem gone.

I am done with it for now and also in the process of moving everything to Nginx now. Tracing faults on Apache always turns into a nightmare, with Nginx I can find errors in a few seconds to a minute.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with Varnish>Apache>PHP-FPM on Centos 6.

I solved it by disabling KeepAlive in Apache.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error appeared, whenever I accessed my site from iOS / MacOS Safari. After the first access from one of those devices, apache kept craching with segmentation faults on any request from any device, until the next restart.

The problem disappeared after disabling Google`s **mod_spdy** module.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to upgrade my system from `ubuntu` 14.04 to 18.04, and got this issue, I downgrade to 16.04 to solve it.

I also upgrade my `php` to 7.0

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact error and I just restarted the server (restarting apache didn't help).

Might consider it if you've just done a `apt upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when there was an infinite loop in my PHP (specifically a function recursively calling itself)