# No Data recieved error in site

Tags: php, apache, magento

we are facing this "No data recieved error" in our magento[php based] site.

we have virtual host error : `Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.1f (internal dummy connection)"`

Apache error : `child pid 30440 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2`

we didt installed APC Opcode in our server to remove cache.

Our server team said there is no varnish in server. is this error related to server or with our php code.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18877719/1190388

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing apc.stat to 0 and 1 to see if it solves anything. You might have to dig with gdb to figure out the exact problem and post it here.

http://sysadmin.carlusgg.com/?p=197

Comment: let us know how it goes :)